# Sencha Touch 2 TypeError

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I've been following [Miami Coder's tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/#comment-2123) on Sencha Touch.

I get this following error:

```
TypeError: ‘undefined’ is not a function (evaluating ‘this.getRandomInt(0, 100)’) Notes.js:20
```

which refers to the following line in the controller:

```
var noteId = (now.getTime()).toString() + (this.getRandomInt(0, 100)).toString();
```

I tried removing the second part of the concatenation and decided to deal with that later but, a new error popped up:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'animation.setLayout(layout)')
```

which refers to: `Container.js:1233`

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> getRandomInt()
> ```

Is a local function which contains the math.random. You should create that function.